# MySQL: Which one should I use and why?

Tags: mysql, node.js, version

I always used MAMP with a Mac, so mysql was already installed in it. But now I switched to node.js and I would like to connect it with mysql, so I have to setup myself.

I'm here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/ but I don't really know what's the difference between them and which one should I use?

Comment: If you havnt got a mySQL server setup yet, look at using more "natural" servers that work with node.js like couch or mongo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MySQL Community Server](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) will do fine.